# What to use in java spring application to create automatically DB or new tables if not exist by application?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am writing a sample application in which I wrote all sql in files.

> Whenever I added new functionality I am creating new sql script.

What technology should I use when my application run first check all the script if not exist create or if any new script added create that one only. I gave files name like **script1.sql,script2.sql** and so on.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a set of sql scripts to set up your DB. Every time you have a modification you add another script - incremental script.

You can use [DB maintain](http://www.dbmaintain.org/tutorial.html) for managing them. It will hold information about which scripts were executed and it will know to just execute the last patch. It seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

1. Keeps track of what scripts were executed ( DB version )
2. Can ease deployment to another environment ( with a lower DB version )
3. Can do much more than that , but it seems this is what you need.

PS Not sure if there are other frameworks which can do the same.

Comment: Thanks. My initial requirement is only this.